# The Fourier-Legendre expansion of a plane wave

Tags: special-functions

I want to perform a Fourier-Legendre expansion on the spatial part of a plane wave.

$$
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\boldsymbol{k} \cdot R-\omega t)}=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(k R \cos\theta-\omega t)}
$$

$$
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k R \cos \theta}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{i}^l(2 l+1) \mathrm{j}_l(k R) \mathrm{P}_l(\cos \theta)
$$

For simplicity in notation, let's use x to represent $\cos \theta$, then we have:

$$
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k R x}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{i}^l(2 l+1) \mathrm{j}_l(k R) \mathrm{P}_l(x)
$$

In mathematical terms, where $\mathrm{j}_l(k R)$ is Spherical Bessel Function of the First Kind `SphericalBesselJ[l,k R]`, $\mathrm{P}_l(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial `LegendreP[l,x]`, and ( i ) is the imaginary unit `I`.

I attempted to use `FindSequenceFunction` to identify a pattern for the coefficients ( $ C_l=\frac{2 l+1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \mathrm{P}_l(x) f(x) \mathrm{d} x, l=0,1,2, \cdots $  ) of the Legendre series, expected outcome is $  \mathrm{i}^l(2 l+1) \mathrm{j}_l(k R)  $. But I did not obtain any results. Is it because the pattern is complex, or is there another reason?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

FindSequenceFunction[FullSimplify[Table[(2 l + 1)/2  Integrate[LegendreP[l, x]  E^(I  k  R  x), {x, -1, 1}], {l, 0, 10}]], l]
```

(*  Failed  *)

**EDIT**

This is the integral result for $ l $ from 0 to 4, all are analytical expressions, but involving trigonometric functions. Does the presence of trigonometric functions affect the discovery of patterns by the `FindSequenceFunction`?

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text { FindSequenceFunction }\left[\left\{\frac{\operatorname{Sin}[k R]}{k R}, \frac{3 i(-k R \operatorname{Cos}[k R]+\operatorname{Sin}[k R])}{k^2 R^2}, \frac{5\left(3 k R \operatorname{Cos}[k R]+\left(-3+k^2 R^2\right) \operatorname{Sin}[k R]\right)}{k^3 R^3},\right.\right. \\
& \left.\left.\quad-\frac{7 i\left(k R\left(-15+k^2 R^2\right) \operatorname{Cos}[k R]+3\left(5-2 k^2 R^2\right) \operatorname{Sin}[k R]\right)}{k^4 R^4}, \frac{9\left(5 k R\left(-21+2 k^2 R^2\right) \operatorname{Cos}[k R]+\left(105-45 k^2 R^2+k^4 R^4\right) \operatorname{Sin}[k R]\right)}{k^5 R^5}\right\}, l\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Are you sure that the integral in the expansion coefficient: `(2  l + 1)/2   Integrate[
  LegendreP[l, x]   E^(I   k   R   x), {x, -1, 1}]` has an analytic solution?

Comment: It appears that the integral results are all in analytical expressions, but they involve trigonometric functions. Take a look at my EDIT. Thank you! @Daniel Huber